# Garbage text everywhere in IntelliJ IDEA IDE

Tags: windows-10, ide, intellij-idea

Recently, all text in my IntelliJ IDEA IDE has become completely unintelligible, and I'm not sure how to fix this. Following is the screenshot.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Might be better as a question over on https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics

Comment: typeface conflict?

Comment: @Yorik It seems it was happening because of the Material Theme UI plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, from the [manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-project-and-ide-settings.html) :

> **Restore the default settings**
>
> To restore the IntelliJ IDEA default settings, you can remove the
>   configuration directory (idea.config.path) when the IDE is not
>   running. The directory is located in:
>
> `<SYSTEM DRIVE>\Users\<USER ACCOUNT NAME>\.<PRODUCT><VERSION>`